# Getting email from Facebook JS API, issue or feature?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the following as a reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

However, I cannot seem to extract an email. I'm not sure whether this is because the user settings don't allow the email, or that this is an issue with the calls I'm making.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }


function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
      var result = JSON.stringify(response);
      alert(response.email)

    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,first_name,last_name'});


<fb:login-button data-scope="email" scope="public_profile, email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">


</fb:login-button>
```

I can login fine, but I get nothing for the email. I don't know if this is a user settings issue or code issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no scope parameter for FB.api, and you are already defining the scope in the login button. There is also no scope called "first_name" or "last_name", those are just fields in the user table.

Anyway, since v2.4 you have to specifiy the fields in the API endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

For example:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email,first_name,last_name'}, function(response) {
  ...
});
```

You can read more about FB.api in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

Btw, there´s an article about login with the JS SDK, if you need more information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/